# Skipping a serial number in MS Access report

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013, ms-access-reports

I am working on an MS Access report. It is about employee service records. This report asks a parameter which is the ID of the staff member and displays multiple records of its punishments. What I wanted was to skip a serial number of records based on type of punishment. For instance, I do want to skip number for a punishment that contains word 'aside'. So for this, I have added a serial number using a textfield making its control source=`IIf([PType] Not Like "*aside*",1,0)` its result like this. 
[image: Punishment report] 

The problem here is number 5 is repeating 2 times(as it contains 'aside' string). But I want that highlighted row shouldn't contain any number and next two to it should be numbered 6 which is correct already. My background is from MS SQL server. I can't handle complex VB code.

Comment: Try setting textbox HideDuplicates property to yes.

Comment: whats the reports SQL/Row Source?